# In Amazon Linux, unable to install pandas and numpy in virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

I have been trying to install `pandas` and `numpy` in my virtualenv. The box is an Amazon Linux AMI instance. This is my command log:

Activate venv and check packages

```
[ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 www]$ source datasci_venv/bin/activate
(datasci_venv) [ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 www]$ pip freeze
Django==1.11
requests==2.20.1
```

Then using `pip install` to install `pandas` and `numpy`. Note that when installing `Django` and `requests`, they were successfully installed:

```
(datasci_venv) [ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 www]$ pip install pandas && pip install numpy
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/d8/feeb346d41f181e83fba45224ab14a8d8af019b48af742e047f3845d8cff/pandas-0.23.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in ./datasci_venv/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pandas) (2018.7)
Collecting numpy>=1.9.0 (from pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/7f/9d804d2348471c67a7d8b5f84f9bc59fd1cefa148986f2b74552f8573555/numpy-1.15.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in ./datasci_venv/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pandas) (2.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./datasci_venv/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.11.0)
Installing collected packages: numpy, pandas
Successfully installed numpy-1.15.4 pandas-0.23.4
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/7f/9d804d2348471c67a7d8b5f84f9bc59fd1cefa148986f2b74552f8573555/numpy-1.15.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
tabula-py 1.3.0 requires pandas, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.15.4
```

So it seems that they are correctly installed, since there are no error messages. However, when I check my packages again, they are not there:

```
(datasci_venv) [ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 www]$ pip freeze
Django==1.11
requests==2.20.1
```

And hence I decided to check which command I am using but it says I'm using the programs in the venv:

```
(datasci_venv) [ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 www]$ which pip
/var/www/datasci_venv/bin/pip
(datasci_venv) [ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 www]$ which python
/var/www/datasci_venv/bin/python
(datasci_venv) [ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 www]$
```

Hence, I'm kinda lost on what to do and check. Any help or solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it appears that pip is installing the package in the lib64 folder of your virtualenv rather than on the lib folder. You need to force the target folder by doing this:

```
pip install --target datasci_venv/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ numpy
```

Hope this help!